# Ubuntu on VMware Fusion resolution not changeable from 800x600

Tags: display, macosx, vmware-fusion

On Ubuntu in "Systems Setting" --> "Display", I only see 800x600 resolution option. As I change the size of the VM window, it just expands/shrink accordingly, maintaining the same ratio (800x600) that is way too narrow for me.

Already tried but no good:

- On VM's setting --> "Display", I tried checking both on/off with "Accelerate 3D Graphics" or "User full resolution for Retina display".
- Add `pref.autoFitGuestToWindow = "FALSE"` to ~/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/preferences (https://communities.vmware.com/message/2342718)

Any idea is appreciated.

- VMWare Fusion 6.0.3 with VMWare Tools installed.
- OSX 10.9.3 on Macbook Pro, Retina 15-inch
- VM: Ubuntu 12.04 64b

Comment: Do the suggestions on the [this page](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2318966) help?

Answer (score 0):

Installing VM Ware tools should help. Main menu-> Virtual Machine -> Install VM Ware tools.

*Make sure you update linux headers, since vmware is notorious for not being able to find them. Plenty of solutions and guides online in case you run into this issue.*